# Limit - Multivariable Calculus

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm having difficulty finding this limit: $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \sqrt{\frac{{|y|}}{|x|}}|y|^{m}$, where $m$ is a positive real number.

I actually stumbled upon this in the middle of a question, where I reduced the original limit to it. Now, I'm stuck.

Wolfram says this limit equals $0$ (and it should be zero), which I "intuitively" understand (because the exponent of the numerator is greater than the denominator, we can even generalize it to $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{x^{a}}{y^{b}}$, where $a > b$).

My approaches were polar coordinates, which reduced it to $r^{m}(\sin{\theta})^{m}\sqrt{\tan{\theta}}$, but this is actually unbounded; and some manipulations to use the squeeze theorem, but nothing great happened.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: let $y=x^{1+2m}$, then $x\rightarrow0$ as $y\rightarrow0$, but the limit equals 1. In the generalized case, set $y=x^{\frac{a}{b}}$.

Comment: Actually that limit does not exist because it has different results  in different restrictions of the domain of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=y=t \to 0$ then

$$ \sqrt{\frac{{|y|}}{|x|}}|y|^{m}=|t|^m \to 0$$

but, as noticed in the comments, for $x=t^{2m+1}$ and $y=t\to 0$ we obtain

$$ \sqrt{\frac{{|y|}}{|x|}}|y|^{m}=1$$

therefore the limit doesn't exist.